# Equivalent of editable ComboBox in WinRT?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

The standard (desktop) windows combobox has three styles; Simple, Dropdown, and Drop List. Dropdown works like an edit control and a combobox, whereas Drop List doesn't allow editing.

Am I missing something, or does the XAML ComboBox control in a Windows 8 store app only support the Drop List style?

I was halfway through implementing something when I ran into this, and the more I look, the more it seems that it just isn't supported.

Do I really need to replace the ComboBoxes in my screens with an edit control followed by a listbox?

Yuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

thanks to edward.ho.tpe's answer I wrote myself a little EditableComboBox by using an `TextBox` inside a `ComboBoxItem`.
If you want to use it multiple times it might be better to create a UserControl.

However this is how I did it:

#### The style:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TransparentBrush" Color="Transparent"/>
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxItemTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource TextSelectionHighlightColorThemeBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-10,0,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style x:Name="DeleteButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonPressedBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"/>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"/>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <Border x:Name="BorderElement" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonBorderThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                                            <Border x:Name="BackgroundElement" Background="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                                <TextBlock x:Name="GlyphElement" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonForegroundThemeBrush}" FontStyle="Normal" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="&#xE0A4;" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            </Border>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource TextControlPointerOverBackgroundThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource TextControlPointerOverBorderThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ButtonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="ButtonVisible"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="ButtonCollapsed"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="BackgroundElement" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
                    <Border x:Name="BorderElement" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextBoxForegroundHeaderThemeBrush}" FontWeight="Semilight" Margin="0,4,0,4" Grid.Row="0"/>
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsTabStop="False" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" ZoomMode="Disabled"/>
                    <ContentControl x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextBoxPlaceholderTextThemeBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsTabStop="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <Button x:Name="DeleteButton" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" IsTabStop="False" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

#### The ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">
        <TextBox x:Name="tbComboBox" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemTextBox}" KeyDown="tbComboBox_KeyDown"/>
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Item 2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Item 3</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Item 4</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

#### The event handlers:

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AddedItems.Count == 1 && e.AddedItems[0] != (sender as ComboBox).Items[0])
    {
        (sender as ComboBox).SelectedIndex = 0;
        tbComboBox.Text = (e.AddedItems[0] as ComboBoxItem).Content as String;
    }
}

private void tbComboBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Space)
    {
        if (tbComboBox.SelectionLength > 0)
        {
            tbComboBox.Text = tbComboBox.Text.Remove(tbComboBox.SelectionStart, tbComboBox.SelectionLength);
            tbComboBox.SelectionLength = 0;
        }
        int pos = tbComboBox.SelectionStart;
        tbComboBox.Text = tbComboBox.Text.Insert(pos, " ");
        tbComboBox.SelectionStart = pos + 1;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

### So basically what this is:

As edward.ho.tpe suggested a `TextBox` as the content of the first item of a `ComboBox`.
The `TextBox` has a custom style that removes the background, the border, moves it a little to the left (optional - but i like it since it provides more space to write), and changes the delete button to stay collapsed.
The `SelectionChanged` event handler makes sure that the `TextBox` stays the `SelectedItem` and only changes the `Text` based on the content of the selected item and the `KeyDown` event handler handles the space keydown because otherwise that would trigger the Dropdown of the `ComboBox`.

Comment: This is not stable with `Space` and `Enter`

Comment: of course it's not.
You can't have both. Either you can enter text (in that case space should not open the dropdown) or you cannot enter text (in that case you just have a normal `ComboBox`). You could disallow spaces in the text for the combobox and remove the keydown but that'd be a rather weird design choice imo.

Answer (score 4):

[Syncfusion Controls for WinRT](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/winrt/controls) includes a ComboBox too. But it is not free.

Comment: Unfortunately, Syncfusion's UWP sfComboBox doesn't provide a property or means to access the entered text.  The text input appears intended only for searching for items in the collection making up the list.

Answer (score 3):

Since combobox item in WinRT can be anything, you can :

```
<ComboBoxItem>
<TextBox Text="something"/>
</ComboBoxItem>
```

When user clicks that item, he/she can edit its content.

It's up to you whether to have the edit result change that item's editbox or just adding a new combobox item to that combobox. Process this in the LostFocus event.

Comment: I don't think having `TextBox`es as items of a `ComboBox` is a good idea for many reasons. First, because it doesn't really address the original question and second - for performance reasons.

Answer (score 2):

You are not missing anything. There is no editable combobox in the out-of-the-box toolbox.

You might have tried the winrt xaml toolkit @ http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/
But that does not have one either. Too bad because it is free.

You might have looked at ComponentOne @ http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/StudioWinRTXAML/
But that does not have one either.

You might have looked at Infragistics @ http://www.infragistics.com/products/technology-previews/windows8/
But that toolkit is in "preview" still.

You might have looked at Telerik @ http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-8/overview.aspx
They have a combobox http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-8/controls/combo-box.aspx

But you might want something free. 
There is no Microsoft XAML Toolkit at this time. 
So you need to build your own or find an open source project.
I could not find such a project at this time.

But what is an editable combobox really? A standard combobox and a textbox, right?

Answer (score 2):

By setting

```
combobox.ComboBoxMode = ComboBoxModes.Editable
```

in syncfusion SfComboBox, you can edit the combobox.

Regards,

Elavarasan M

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question but for new searchers like me I found the property  [ComboBox.IsEditable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.iseditable(v=vs.110).aspx) is fine

Answer (score 1):

[image: AutoSuggestBox UI Control]

Try The UIControl called [AutoSuggestBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.autosuggestbox)

```
<AutoSuggestBox PlaceholderText="Company">
     <AutoSuggestBox.QueryIcon>
         <SymbolIcon Symbol="find"/>
     </AutoSuggestBox.QueryIcon>
</AutoSuggestBox>
```

Comment: This is good for filtering items, but what if you want to present N standard choices, or allow a user to type in a custom value?

That was my original intent.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched everywhere for a Searchable Combobox and have resolved to writing my own. It is not quite like your editable combobox, but will filter the options in a combobox when typing. Maybe this could help someone.

You would define a new control like this:

```
<control:SearchableComboBox Margin='5'
          x:Name='ComboBoxCountry'
          ItemsSourceList='{Binding CountryList}'
          ItemsSourceListBase='{Binding CountryListBase}'
          PlaceholderText='Select Country'/>
```

Unfortunately you still need to provide a duplicate list, CountryListBase. If you have suggestions on improving this, let me know!

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;

namespace eMoyoConnect.Controls
{
    public class SearchableComboBox : ComboBox
    {

        public ObservableCollection<string> ItemsSourceList
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(ItemsSourceListProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ItemsSourceListProperty, value);
                this.ItemsSource = ItemsSourceList;
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceListProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSourceList", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(SearchableComboBox),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, ItemsSourceListChanged));

        private static void ItemsSourceListChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var plv = d as SearchableComboBox;
            plv.ItemsSource = e.NewValue;
        }

        public Collection<string> ItemsSourceListBase
        {
            get { return (Collection<string>)GetValue(ItemsSourceListBaseProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ItemsSourceListBaseProperty, value);
                this.ItemsSource = ItemsSourceListBase;
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceListBaseProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSourceListBase", typeof(Collection<string>), typeof(SearchableComboBox),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, ItemsSourceListBaseChanged));

        private static void ItemsSourceListBaseChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var plv = d as SearchableComboBox;
            plv.ItemsSource = e.NewValue;
        }

        string FilterString = "";
        protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsLetterOrSpace(e.Key))
            {
                if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Space)
                    FilterString += " ";
                else
                    FilterString += e.Key.ToString();
                FilterList(FilterString);
                this.ItemsSource = ItemsSourceList;
                if (ItemsSourceList.Count > 0)
                    this.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
            else if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Back)
            {
                if (FilterString.Length > 0)
                {
                    FilterString = FilterString.Substring(0, FilterString.Length - 1);
                    FilterList(FilterString);
                    this.ItemsSource = ItemsSourceList;
                    if (ItemsSourceList.Count > 0)
                        this.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
            }

            if (e.Key != VirtualKey.Space)
            {
                base.OnKeyDown(e);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnGotFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string selectedValue = "";
            if (this.SelectedValue != null)
                selectedValue = (string)this.SelectedValue;
            FilterString = "";
            FilterList(FilterString);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedValue))
                this.SelectedValue = selectedValue;
        }

        internal void FilterList(string FilterString)
        {
            ItemsSourceList.Clear();
            IEnumerable<string> list;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterString))
                list = ItemsSourceListBase.Where(x => x.StartsWith(FilterString));
            else
                list = ItemsSourceListBase;
            foreach (var item in list)
                ItemsSourceList.Add(item);
        }

        private bool IsLetterOrSpace(VirtualKey key)
        {
            return (key == VirtualKey.A
                || key == VirtualKey.B
                || key == VirtualKey.C
                || key == VirtualKey.D
                || key == VirtualKey.E
                || key == VirtualKey.F
                || key == VirtualKey.G
                || key == VirtualKey.H
                || key == VirtualKey.I
                || key == VirtualKey.J
                || key == VirtualKey.K
                || key == VirtualKey.L
                || key == VirtualKey.M
                || key == VirtualKey.N
                || key == VirtualKey.O
                || key == VirtualKey.P
                || key == VirtualKey.Q
                || key == VirtualKey.R
                || key == VirtualKey.S
                || key == VirtualKey.T
                || key == VirtualKey.U
                || key == VirtualKey.V
                || key == VirtualKey.W
                || key == VirtualKey.X
                || key == VirtualKey.Y
                || key == VirtualKey.Z
                || key == VirtualKey.Space);
        }
    }
}
```