# Can't Input Text into Combo Box

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I am new to Windows 8.1 apps and I have got a combo box that I wan't to be able to input tet into as well as select from drop down. However I cant input any text and I cant find any way to change the "Readonly" variable and setting the "IsEnabled" doesn't work. I am working in VS 2013, Can any one please help

Comment: WinRT doesn't have built-in editable combobox, [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16025064/equivalent-of-editable-combobox-in-winrt)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the direction of an explanation Will have to find a way around it